using Pandas reading a textcolumn longer than 4096 characters from csv
In my csv there is a JSON object, which could be longer than 4096 characters. The pd.read_csv seems to have a problem because i cannot convert this to a valid JSON object to read from.
I used pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', 100000) to display the full column to check
import pandas as pd
import json

# full length (rmobject is about 4500 characters long)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', 100000)
check = pd.read_csv("check.txt")

print(check.rmObject)


def create_dataframe(i):
    rm = check['rmObject']
     # change a single quote in the values to a * 
    obj = json.loads(rm[i].replace("'", '*')) 
    
    #some extra code deleted
for k in range(len(check)):
        result = pd.concat([result, create_dataframe(k)], ignore_index=True)

# Print or do something with the final result
print(result)`


In the statement     obj = json.loads(rm[i].replace("'", '*')) it returns: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes
The 'print(check.rmObject)' returns a cut off string at the 4096 length mark.
Any options?
have tried chunksize to read the file, but to no avail

the question is not clear.  are you saying that the code fails at the print(check.rmObject) line or in the create_dataframe(i) function ?

how to ask a good question:
how to ask

In the statement obj = json.loads(rm[i].replace("'", '*')) it returns: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes.
Is it related to a hard limit for a column (4096) read by the pd.read_csv?

The problem has been resolved. It was a PEBCAK. I was looking at an CSV file but was reading another one, the other one had bad columns in it.
